# %q in inline assembly with -arch i386

Tags: c, assembly, cross-compiling, inline-assembly

I'm working with a library (pulseaudio, src/pulsecore/svolume_mmx.c) that has code similar to the following dummy code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int32_t x = 5;
  int32_t *p_x = &x;
#if defined(__i386__)
  int32_t tmp;
#elif defined(__amd64__)
  int64_t tmp;
#endif

  __asm__ __volatile__ (
    " xor %1, %1                    \n\t"
    " movd (%q0, %1, 4), %%mm0      \n\t"
    " emms                          \n\t"
    : "+r" (p_x), "+r" (tmp)
  );
  printf("%"PRId32"\n", x);
  return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to compile this as a 32-bit library on 64-bit mac osx. When I compile this normally, everything works fine, but when I compile it as the desired 32-bit library with the -arch flag, this happens:

```
$ gcc -std=c99 -arch i386 -o main main.c
/var/folders/random_stuff_here.s:22:bad register name `%rcx, %edx,4)'
```

After reading the assembly output of gcc, the problem is in the movd line. The %q0 register is being filled in as %rcx, which is a 64-bit register. The assembler is attempting to create a 32-bit output from this, and is failing.

I couldn't find much about what the 'q' in %q0 means, but I eventually found documentation for a [different compiler](http://www.pgroup.com/doc/pgiug.pdf) (on page 194) which describes the q as meaning "Produces the quad word register name for an operand if the target supports quad word. Otherwise, it produces a word register name. (For example, if operand 0 is in register 'a', then %q0 produces %rax on x86_64 or %eax on x86.)" It appears that the code generation for the asm block outputs 64-bit registers if you ask for it with the 'q' flag, even if the -arch flag is specifying a 32-bit output.

Using the -m32 flag in addition to the -arch i386 flag doesn't help at all. How can I tell the asm code generator to only use 32-bit registers for %qx symbols? I'd prefer to give extra flags to gcc over modifying the source of this library.

Comment: My GCC doesn't even accept the `-arch` argument. What GCC version are you using?

Comment: the -arch flag is apple-specific.

$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin11
Configured with: {default stuff here}
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.9.00)

Comment: Well, I don't have an Apple around, but you can try `-march=i686` or something similar.

Comment: Just tried it. It doesn't help :-(

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the gcc you have doesn't like explicit mix of a `%q` and a *normal* register in the addressing expression, and/or evaluates `%q` to a 64bit reg name even though you're explicitly compiling for 32bit (and it doesn't exist there).

But then, the use of that in your / your libraries particular `__asm__` expression is rather phony because of your (mis)matching use of (non-)pointer data types in an addressing expression. You can correct that relatively easily:

```
#include <stdint.h>    // has [u]intptr_t and "sized types" [u]int(8|16|32|64)_t
...
int myintval = 0;
int tmp = 0;

__asm__("mov (%0, %1, 4), ..."
    : : "r"((void*)(intptr_t)myintval), "r"((void*)(intptr_t)tmp));
```

I.e. manually force the data types first to `[u]intptr_t` (an integer type of the same underlaying size as a pointer indifferent of whether you're on a 32bit or 64bit platform) and then to an actual pointer (`void*`), which you pass into the input register constraint.

This makes sure the compiler assigns your integer variable(s) to a register usable for addressing operations; the code will work correctly in both 32bit and 64bit x86, and there's no need to use explicit register width specifiers.

Cost/Disadvantages ? Well, in 64bit, if you *work* with the registers instead of just using them for addressing, then e.g. `xor %...,%...` becomes an explicit `xorq %r...,%r...` (with REX prefix) even though that's not strictly required. If you can't take that, use `#ifdef`/`#else` to create a 32bit and a 64bit code block.

On a side note, if you can't / don't want to modify the library sources then rather try to get a different gcc version (download a newer XCode). I've not been able to reproduce your problem with gcc 3.4.5 and various 4.[14567].x, but don't have any 4.2.x at hand.